# How do I fix my table top from chemical damage?

Tags: wooden-furniture

I do acrylic nails and I'm usually pretty cautious, but today I've had either monomer liquid or acetone leak through my many layers of towels.

It has caused the finish on my table to blister and take on the print of the towel fabric. The table is stained and I don't want to have to sand too much of it off so that it requires re-staining. What can I do to repair this?

Comment: A picture would be helpful.

Answer (score 4):

A picture would be SOOOOOO helpful. As well, knowing what the finish is and even what the table is made of.

Even without that information, almost certainly the only fix will be to strip down the (entire) surface of the table. At least it is the only fix that will look any good. You will never get a uniformly good looking solution otherwise.